# ansible-playbook extra vars order and precedence

Tags: ansible

I am running `ansible-playbook` with multiple `--extra-vars` like

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars @vars_a.yml --extra-vars @vars_b.yml --extra-vars @vars_c.yml
```

What is the precedende for these extra vars? Will `vars_a.yml` override `vars_c.yml` or vice versa?

Comment: Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this with `ansible-playbook` version 2.12.1. Vars given later in the command will override earlier vars. So `vars_c.yml` would override vars in `a` and `b`.